# Prove that ${\sqrt {n} }^{\sqrt {n+1}} > {\sqrt {n+1}}^{\sqrt {n}};n=7,8,9...$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Prove that ${\sqrt {n} }^{\sqrt {n+1}} > {\sqrt {n+1}}^{\sqrt {n}};n=7,8,9...$
>
> **SOURCE :** "Inequalities proposed in CRUX Mathematicorum"

I tried induction, but could not prove it.

Can anybody provide a hint ?

Comment: Log both sides...

Answer (score 5):

One can check the case $n=7$ by hand.

Taking logarithms on both sides, the inequality becomes :
$$\sqrt{n+1}\log \sqrt n > \sqrt{n}\log \sqrt{n+1} $$
$${\sqrt{n+1}\over \log \sqrt{n+1}} > {\sqrt n \over \log \sqrt n} $$
So, it is enough to prove $f(x) = \frac{x}{\log x}$ is increasing for $x\ge \sqrt 8$, the easiest way to do that is showing $f'(x)>0$ for $x\ge \sqrt 8$.

Using the quotient rule, 
$$f'(x)= {\log x-1\over (\log x)^2}$$
, which is obviously positive as $\sqrt 8> e$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=2\ln(\ln x)-\ln x$ where $x\in(e^2,\infty)$, then
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\Big(\frac{2}{\ln x}-1\Big)<0$$
so
\begin{eqnarray}
2\ln(\ln(n+1))-\ln (n+1)&<&2\ln(\ln n)-\ln n\\
2\ln(\ln(n+1))-2\ln(\ln n)&<&\ln (n+1)-\ln n\\
2\ln\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}&<&\ln\frac{n+1}{n}\\
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}&<&\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\\
\sqrt{n}\ln(n+1)&<&\sqrt{n+1}\ln n\\
(n+1)^\sqrt{n}&<&n^\sqrt{n+1}\\
\sqrt{n+1}^\sqrt{n}&<&\sqrt{n}^\sqrt{n+1}
\end{eqnarray}